# Selecting null and non-null values in a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I want to return all the work orders where the FacilityCode equals @SelectedFacilityCode except where it equals 'Any'. Then I want it to return all work orders including work orders where FacilityCode is null. The problem is when FacilityCode = FacilityCode, it only returns all the work orders where FacilityCode isn't null. How do I return both null and non-null values when @SelectedFacilityCode = 'Any'?

My actual query is more complex than this but this is the crux of the problem. I'm using SQL Server if that helps.

Thanks!

```
SELECT * FROM WorkOrders
WHERE FacilityCode = CASE
  WHEN @SelectedFacilityCode = 'Any' THEN FacilityCode
  ELSE @SelectedFacilityCode
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is an *expression* not a *statement* i.e. it can only return a value not an expression. You want logical operators (AND/OR) e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkOrders
WHERE @SelectedFacilityCode = 'Any'
OR FacilityCode = @SelectedFacilityCode
```

I highly recommend learning the use of [logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL because they are a core building block for writing queries. Including the use of parentheses to ensure correct ordering.

Comment: Since the query is more complicated, as stated above, I wanted to note for OP that these two `or`'d conditions should most likely be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for this! Once I thought about it for a bit, I realized I was barking up the wrong tree. I converted my whole query like this and it's working properly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkOrders
WHERE @SelectedFacilityCode in ('Any', FacilityCode)
```